# By getting the ID from the database and retrieving the corresponding details

Tags: php, database, android-studio

Im trying to get the Id from the user and result must display the Details from the particular row of ID.. im using PHP connected to android studio there is no errors in android studio but when i try to view the web address of the PHP code i get thsis NULL values. I want to display the data from my database

{"result":[{"name":null,"username":null,"email":null,"age":null,"password":null}]}

here is my code of PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

    $id  = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='".$id."'";

    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

    $result = array();

    array_push($result,array(
        "name"=>$res['name'],
        "username"=>$res['username'],
        "email"=>$res['email'],
        "age"=>$res['age'],
        "password"=>$res['password']
        )
    );

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);

}
```

Comment: since the $res is an array why you created a new one and push values on it !! try to do a print_r($res); to see if the array is full of data or not ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting a value from **$_GET['id'];** ?

Maybe the reason why it gives null values is because the **$id** is null too.

Try including the value of id on the json so that you can see the value of the id in the logcat.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

$id  = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='".$id."'";

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$result = array();

array_push($result,array(
    "id"=>$GET['id'],
    "name"=>$res['name'],
    "username"=>$res['username'],
    "email"=>$res['email'],
    "age"=>$res['age'],
    "password"=>$res['password']
    )
);

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

}
```